# What is the point of on-chip hardware accelerators, instead of that functionality being added as an instruction to the ISA?

Tags: cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I get that if a specialized operation is known to be common, it makes sense to do it in hardware. But at that point, why not make it a part of the ISA so it can be even faster? 
Is there a benefit to making it a co-processor that communicates through shared memory?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hand-wavy because I don't actually design hardware, but I think I know enough to say something that's at least plausible.

---

Adding it to the ISA means it has to be fairly tightly coupled to the pipeline, which doesn't fit well for things like integrated GPUs that have some specialized hardware and can filter out which pixels even need to be processed using dedicated hardware instead of software branching.

Even considering less complicated accelerators (e.g. for crypto):

Especially on simpler CPUs without out-of-order exec and large reordering windows, high-latency HW accelerators could stall the pipeline and stop it from getting other work done while waiting for a result.

Intel does tend to add things to the ISA, such as AES and SHA, because mainstream x86 CPUs do have the instruction throughput and vector registers to feed data to execution units that do one round of AES, for example.

If the accelerator is physically large but usually not needed by multiple cores at once, having groups of cores share one is more natural with some kind of co-processor arrangement to insulate the core from the round-trip latency of going off-core to compute something.

---

Also for GPUs, a GPU has more computational throughput than you can fit down the superscalar pipeline of a normal CPU.  The FLOPS of an integrated GPU is typically much greater than a single core of a modern Intel CPU, even with 2x 256-bit FMA units.  So you'd need to have a CPU instruction like "run shader" that runs a GPU program using its own separately-programmable machine code.  GPU instruction scheduling is lighter weight than even a normal in-order CPU.